# Kafka 0.10 Java Client TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a single node, multi (3) broker Zookeeper / Kafka setup. I am using the Kafka 0.10 Java client.

I wrote following simple remote (on a different Server than Kafka) Producer (in the code I replaced my public IP address with MYIP):

```
Properties config = new Properties();
try {
    config.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "MYIP:9092, MYIP:9093, MYIP:9094");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    producer = new KafkaProducer<String, byte[]>(config);
    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    schema = parser.parse(GATEWAY_SCHEMA);
    recordInjection = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema);
    GenericData.Record avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    //Filling in avroRecord (code not here)
    byte[] bytes = recordInjection.apply(avroRecord);

    Future<RecordMetadata> future = producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>(datasetId+"", "testKey", bytes));
    RecordMetadata data = future.get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My server properties for the 3 brokers look like this (in the 3 different server properties files broker.id is 0, 1, 2 and listeners is PLAINTEXT://:9092, PLAINTEXT://:9093, PLAINTEXT://:9094 and host.name is 10.2.0.4, 10.2.0.5, 10.2.0.6).
This is the first server properties file:

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka1-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

When I execute the code, I get following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for 100101-0
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.valueOrError(FutureRecordMetadata.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:52)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.FutureRecordMetadata.get(FutureRecordMetadata.java:25)
    at com.nr.roles.gateway.GatewayManager.addTransaction(GatewayManager.java:212)
    at com.nr.roles.gateway.gw.service(gw.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 1 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for 100101-0
```

Does anyone know what I am missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: I also tried to do the same as above, but with only one broker (on port 9092). I still get the exact same Exception. I made sure the broker and zookeeper ports on remote machine are open and I can telnet them from the Producer machine.

Answer (score 4):

I encounter the same problems.

You should change your kafka server.properties to specify ip address. 
eg:

`PLAINTEXT://YOUIP:9093`

if not, kafka will use hostname, if the producer can not get the host, it can not send message to kafka even if you can telnet them.

Comment: i have my property set right in  my server.properties as,  listeners=PLAINTEXT://domain_name:9092,But still getting this exception org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch Expired
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException, while connecting from external server, i have increased request.timeout.ms  to a higher values too.

Answer (score 1):

Port information in your `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` configuration is incorrect (MYIP:**9092**).

As you've mentioned in server.properties as "PLAINTEXT://:9093, PLAINTEXT://:9093, PLAINTEXT://:9094".

Comment: sorry, i had a typo here, in server.properties it is "PLAINTEXT://:9092, PLAINTEXT://:9093, PLAINTEXT://:9094".  So the `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` ports are correct.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794261/2246679) answer shares some insight. You can increase the [request.timeout.ms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs) producer configuration which will allow the client to queue batches for longer before expiring.

You might also want to look into the [batch.size](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs) and [linger.ms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs) configurations and find the optimal that works in your case.