# kafka server TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have Kafka instances running in 2 different VMs. I'm able to send messages to Kafka running in vm-1 using spring kafka-template, but while sending a message to kafka running in vm-2, I'm getting the exception below:

> 2018-04-19 15:12:57 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR
>   o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a
>   message with key='xxxx' and payload='{79, 98, 106, 1, 4, 22, 97, 118,
>   114, 111, 46, 115, 99, 104, 101, 109, 97, -28, 51, 123, 34, 116,
>   12...' to topic xxxxxx-v1: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
>   for xxxxxx-v1-3: 60043 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger
>   time

**Producer configuration**

```
config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, x.x.x.x:port);
config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
config.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1048576);
config.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 100);
config.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 10485760);
config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

I can telnet to both VMs and also ping them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46750420

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka Producer error Expiring 10 record(s) for TOPIC:XXXXXX: 6686 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750420/kafka-producer-error-expiring-10-records-for-topicxxxxxx-6686-ms-has-passed)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two brokers and you are able to send messages to one broker and not the other means that you *might* have mis-configured the other broker.

Check your advertised-listeners of the failed broker.

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://1.2.3.4:9092
```

P.S: PLAINTEXT is a protocol and *may* need to be changed in your case. The IP must be accessible to your producer.

Additionally, you may also want to check the `message.max.bytes` on your broker  or `max.message.bytes` on topic is greater than your `max.request.size` of your producer. To debug this, try sending small messages, if they also give the same error, then this is not the problem.

Reference: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868764/2534090)