# Kafka producer throws 'TimeoutException: Batch Expired' exception

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I'm Testing Spring Cloud Stream App for twitter,
Started the docker container with the following Environment properties related to Kafka,

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=<ip>
advertised.host.name=<ip>:9092
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=twitter-source-test
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=<ip>:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=<ip>:2181
```

My kafka producerConfig values follows,

```
 2017-01-12 14:47:09.979  INFO 1 --- [itterSource-1-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
compression.type = none
metric.reporters = []
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
bootstrap.servers = [192.168.127.188:9092]
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
buffer.memory = 33554432
timeout.ms = 30000
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
block.on.buffer.full = false
ssl.key.password = null
max.block.ms = 60000
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
ssl.truststore.password = null
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
metrics.num.samples = 2
client.id = 
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.protocol = TLS
request.timeout.ms = 30000
ssl.provider = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
ssl.keystore.location = null
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
retries = 0
max.request.size = 1048576
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
linger.ms = 0
```

2017-01-12 14:47:09.985  INFO 1 --- [itterSource-1-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 0.9.0.1

But the producer continuously throws the following exception,

```
2017-01-12 14:47:42.196 ERROR 1 --- [ad | producer-3] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{-1, 1, 11, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 0, 0, 0, 12, 34, 116, 101, 120, 116...' to topic twitter-source-test:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch Expired
```

I can telnet from my docker container to the broker 192.168.127.188:9092 and 2181. Also my kafka server is **not a docker container**.

Saw some solution like adding 'advertised.host.name' but doesn't worked, or is it the correct way that I have given the env props.

Any help?

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794260/when-does-the-apache-kafka-client-throw-a-batch-expired-exception

Comment: setting **listeners** in server.properties resolves the problem. Thank you. eg: listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing the fix.

Setting listeners in server.properties resolves the problem. eg: `listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092`