# Apache Kafka in docker AND VirtualBox VM

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, apache-kafka, virtualbox

I'm trying to use Apache Kafka, i.e. a version usable in connection with docker (wurstmeister/kafka-docker), in a Virtual Machine and connect to the kafka broker in the dockers over the host system of the VM.

I will describe the setup in more detail:

My host system is an Ubuntu 64 bit 14.04.3 LTS (Kernel 3.13) running on an "usual" computer. I have a complete and complex structure of various docker-containers interacting with each other. In order to not disturb, or better said, to encapsulate this whole structure, it is not an option to run the docker images directly on the host system. Another reason for that is the need for different python libraries on the host, which interfere with the python-lib version required by docker-compose  (which is used to start the different docker images).

Therefore the desired solution should be to setup a virtual machine over VirtualBox (guest system: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) and to completely run the docker  environment in this VM. This has the distinct advantage that the VM itself can be configured exactly according to the requirements of the docker structure.

As mentioned above one of the docker images provides kafka and zookeeper functionality to use for communication and messaging. That means the .yaml file, which sets up a container running this image, forwards all necessary ports of kafka and zookeeper to the host system of the docker environment (which is the guest system of the virtual box VM). In order to also make the docker environment visible in the host system, I forwarded all the ports over network settings in VirtualBox (network -> adapter NAT -> advanced -> port forwarding). The behaviour of the system is as follows:

When I run the docker-environment (including kafka) I can connect, consume and produce from the VM-kafka, which uses the recommended standard kafka shell scripts (producer & consumer api).

When I run a Kafka and zookeeper server ON THE VM guest system, I can connect from outside the VM (host), produce and consume over producer & consumer api.

When I run Kafka in the docker environment I **can** connect from the host system outside the VM, meaning I can see all topics, get infos about topics, while also seeing some debug output from kafka and zookeeper in the docker.

What is not possible is unfortunately to produce or consume any message from the host system to/from the docker-kafka. From the producer API I get a "Batch expired" exception, the consumer returns with a "ClosedChannelException".

I have done a lot of googling and found a lot of hints how to solve similiar problems. Most of them refer to the advertised.host.name-parameter in kafka-server.properties, which is accessible over KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in .yaml. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374057/3770602 e.g. refers to that parameter when both the errors mentioned above occur. Unfortunately none of the scenarios feature both docker AND VM functionality.

Further more trying to modify this parameter does not have an affect at all. Although I am not very familiar with docker **and** kafka, I can see a problem here, as the kafka consumer and producer would get the local IP of the docker environment, which is 10.0.2.15 in the NAT case, to use as broker. But unfortunately this IP is not visibile from outside the VM. Consequently the solution would probably be a changed setup, where one should use the bridged mode in VirtualBox networking. Strange thing here is, that a bridged connection (of course) leads to an own IP of the VM over DHCP, which then leads to a non-accessible docker-kafka **both** from the VM **AND** the host system. This last behaviour seems to be very awkward to me.

Concluding my question would be, if somebody has some experiences with this or a similiar scenario and can tell me, how to configure docker-kafka, VirtualBox VM and host system. I have really tried a lot of different settings for the consumer and producer call with no success. Of course some docker, kafka or both docker & kafka experts are welcome to answer as well.

If you need additional information or you can provide some hints, please let me know.

Thanks in advance