# Kafka producer TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Kafka with **Spring-boot:**

**Kafka Producer class**:

```java
@Service
public class MyKafkaProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationDispatcherSender.class);

    // Send Message
    public void sendMessage(String topicName, String message) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("========topic Name===== " + topicName + "=========message=======" + message);
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> result = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
        result.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                LOGGER.debug("sent message='{}' with offset={}", message, result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                LOGGER.error(Constants.PRODUCER_MESSAGE_EXCEPTION.getValue() + " : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Kafka-configuration:**

```
spring.kafka.producer.retries=0
spring.kafka.producer.batch-size=100000
spring.kafka.producer.request.timeout.ms=30000
spring.kafka.producer.linger.ms=10
spring.kafka.producer.acks=0
spring.kafka.producer.buffer-memory=33554432
spring.kafka.producer.max.block.ms=5000
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=192.168.1.161:9092,192.168.1.162:9093
```

Let's say I have sent 10 times 1000 messages in topic `my-test-topic`.

8 out of 10 times I am successfully getting all messages in my consumer but sometimes I am getting this below **error**:

`2017-10-05 07:24:11, [ERROR] [my-service - LoggingProducerListener - onError:76] Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{"deviceType":"X","deviceKeys":[{"apiKey":"X-X-o"}],"devices...' to topic my-test-topic`

and `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for my-test-topic-4 due to 30024 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time`

Comment: Is this error you are describing from the producer or the consumer?

Comment: I am getting this error on producer

Comment: So, your batch is too slow for such a "low" `request.timeout.ms`. Try to make `batch-size` a bit lower

Comment: Isn't 30 second enough?( I am new to Kafka, please bear with me)

Comment: I don't know, but according your error you are really exceeding those 30 secs: `due to 30024 ms has passed`

Comment: any news here? I've got the same issue with spring cloud stream and kafka binder

Answer (score 20):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. Increase `request.timeout.ms` - this is the time that Kafka will wait for whole batch to be ready in buffer. So in your case if there are less than 100 000 messages in buffer, timeout will occur. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794261/2707179
2. Decrease `batch-size` - related to previous point, it will send batches more often but they will include fewer messages.
3. Depending on message size, maybe your network cannot catch up with high load? Check if your throughput is not a bottleneck.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP ever since I enabled SSL on Kafka, and notice that, like me, he has set `linger.ms`. According to the documentation, batches are sent out after this linger time even if the batch is not full, so even with a high batch size it should not time out.

Comment: @michalbrz After reading and understanding these two articles: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/34794261/4038460 and 2) https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_performance.html . I felt that we should increase batch-size to avoid timeout. If we increase batch-size -> Number of batches will be reduced -> Number of requests will decrease -> Time taken to send records will decrease -> Timeout will not occur frequently

Comment: `request.timeout.ms` tells how much time the batch can remain in the buffer before it times out. It is not the time Kafka waits for the buffer to be filled.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue during times of low volumes, during which the 3 possibilities do not apply.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had `replication factor < min.insync.replicas`. A write could never get enough acknowledgments and therefore timed out.
Recreating the topic with `replication factor > min.insync.replicas` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

1. First clue in the error is `30024 ms has passed` - the configuration `spring.kafka.producer.request.timeout.ms=30000` is related. This 30 seconds wait is for filling up the buffer on the Producer side.
2. When a message is published, it gets buffered at the Producer's side and it will wait for 30s (see config above) to fill up. `spring.kafka.producer.batch-size=100000` means 100KB so if the message ingestion load is low, and the buffer doesn't fill up with more messages to 100KB in 30s, you would expect this message.
3. `spring.kafka.producer.linger.ms=10` is used where the **ingestion load is high** and the producer wants to limit `send()` calls to Kafka brokers. This is the duration Producer will wait before sending messages to the broker after batch is ready (i.e. after buffer is filled up to batch size of 100KB).

Solution:

- Increase `linger.ms` to hold messages longer after the batch is ready. If more time is needed to fill the batch, increase `request.timeout.ms`.
- Another approach: reduce `batch-size`, or increase `request.timeout.ms`, or both.

Comment: 1. **Completely wrong**, see documentation: "The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request".
2. **Completely wrong**, see above.
3. **Completely wrong**, see documentation: "once we get batch.size worth of records for a partition it will be sent immediately regardless of this setting, however if we have fewer than this many bytes accumulated for this partition we will 'linger' for the specified time waiting for more records to show up"

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue by addressing correctly the host **spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers with its DNS**. Even if the network resolves the IP addresses, it seems to need the DNS.