# Kafka Producer Time out

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, producer

I try to publish a message to kafka using Spring Boot.

I can telnet, ping kafka.

I get this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for geofencemonitorrequests-0: 240036 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Add sample code, that you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka producer TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649748/kafka-producer-timeoutexception-expiring-1-records)

Comment: I already setup all configure in the above the guilde but it doesn't work.
I also get error when set message via kafka-console-producer.bat.