# Publish Kafka objects in batches

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using KafkaProducer.send() method to publish records to Kafka.
This is an asynchronous method. My application is publishing about 20k records to Kafka. A lot of times after successfully sending about 10k records I get Timeout Exception. I increased batch.size and linger.ms which reduced the problem but i still get Timeout Exception sometimes.
Is there a way to send only 10k records at a time wait for them to complete and then send the next batch?? I do not want to make it synchronous by using send.get() because that will make it very slow.
This is the exception I am getting.

```
Error publishing object on partition 0 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
```

Comment: Did you try to use flush()? This will block your producer and make all the messages "send ready".

Comment: Here's another question with exactly same exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649748/kafka-producer-timeoutexception-expiring-1-records

Comment: I am using flush() after sending every message. I do not think that is working for me.

Comment: why are you using `flush()` after each record?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try set `retries=3` to the producer config?
And probably in case of record expiration you should not increase `batch.size` but decrease it.

Comment: Yes, *smaller* batches seem better if you run into timeouts. And be aware that retries can result in messages being produced out of order, which may or may not be a problem for your application.

Comment: @Thilo How do I send it in batches??

Comment: The producer does this automatically, according to configuration (such as `batch.size`)