# Kafka Timeout Exception:Batch Expired

Tags: apache-kafka

We are facing following issue on production:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch Expired.
```

Is it because of invalid configuration like batch size, request timeout or any other thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794260/when-does-the-apache-kafka-client-throw-a-batch-expired-exception

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that some records are put into the queue at a faster rate than they can be sent from the client.

When your Producer sends messages, they are stored in buffer (before sending the to the target broker) and the records are grouped together into batches in order to increase throughput. When a new record is added to the batch, it must be sent within a -configurable- time window which is controlled by `request.timeout.ms` (the default is set to 30 seconds). If the batch is in the queue for longer time, a `TimeoutException` is thrown and the batch records will then be removed from the queue and won't be delivered to the broker.

Increasing the value of `request.timeout.ms` should do the trick for you.

Comment: we already tried it out but it didn't work for us. What batch size should be preferred ?

Comment: @user3392430 It depends on the volume of your data. Note that if the `batch.size` is to small, the producer will need to send messages more frequently. By the way, did you restart your services after changing the configurations?

Comment: @user3392430 Did you also get a `ChannelClosedException`?

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes we restarted the services after making the configuration changes and didn't get ChannelClosedException

Comment: what are the other possible reasons which may cause this exception?

Comment: What is the value of linger.ms?